# How do I enable or disable Apport?

Tags: apport

The system crash dialog is annoying me, how can I turn it off? I'd also like to know how to turn it back on just in case I need it to report a problem.

Comment: since this seems to effect numerous people, is it a bug with apport itself?

Comment: Not sure but I also think the crash dump may contain full text files for ex. so if you have sensitive data on it, better keep it disabled. I think, every time a crash happens and that pops up, we should be clearly informed that a crash dump of like 200MB will be uploaded and it will contain data you were editing on the application. I finally found something that I dislike on ubuntu :(, never thought this day would come...

Comment: Please follow the instructions from the official [Apport article in the Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Apport).

Answer (score 270, accepted):

**As of Ubuntu 16.04 systemd apport does not seem to honor its config file**

The systemd commands to enable / disable apport are:

Disable

```
sudo systemctl disable apport.service
```

If that does not work, you would then need to mask the service

```
systemctl mask apport.service
```

To reenable

```
systemctl unmask apport.service # if you masked it
sudo systemctl enable apport.service
```

---

Previous versions of Ubuntu:

You need to edit `/etc/default/apport`. The following changes will prevent Apport from starting at boot:

---

**Graphical**:
Open a terminal with (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and type this:

```
sudo -i gedit /etc/default/apport
```

and then push <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. You password is being typed, but will not display as dots.

or

**Command line**:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/apport
```

---

A file editor is now open. Change enabled from "0" to a "1" so it looks like this:

```
enabled=1
```

To turn it off make it:

```
enabled=0
```

---

Now save your changes and close the file editor. Apport will now no longer start at boot. If you want to turn it off immediately without rebooting, run `sudo service apport stop`.

You can also use `sudo service apport stop` without modifying `/etc/default/apport` to turn it off temporarily.

See also:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Apport
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs#A4._Collect_information_about_the_bug

Comment: Isn't it the case that "service apport stop" will stop it for the present, and setting enabled=0 is what turns it off at boot?

Comment: @SilvioLevy yes, that's correct. I've updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: should `systemctl` be used now since the switch to systemd from upstart?

Answer (score 41):

**On Unity**: 17.04 and below:

1. Click on Ubuntu icon, search for "System settings"
2. Select Privacy > Diagnostics tab
3. Unlock
4. Tick "Send error reports to Canonical"

   [image: Ubuntu 12.04 > Privacy > Diagnostics tab > Send error reports to Canonical]

   On GNOME: 17.10+

   [image: GNOME > Problem reporting screenshot]

Comment: This didn't seem to do anything for me, still getting system error pop ups.

Comment: I had this checked, and it still wasn't sending error reports.  Looks like it has to be enabled from the command line.

Comment: btw, it didnt change `/etc/default/apport`

Answer (score 34):

```
sudo service apport stop ; sudo sed -ibak -e s/^enabled\=1$/enabled\=0/ /etc/default/apport ; sudo mv /etc/default/apportbak ~
```

The above script should stop apport, then take a backup of its configuration file, disable apport on boot, and lastly moves the backup to your home directory.

Comment: Thanks! Out of all three of the answers, only this one worked for my friend when we overwrote Ubuntu onto his Chromebook!

Answer (score 14):

On newer versions of ubuntu (15.04+)

To stop the service:

```
systemctl stop apport.service
```

To disable the service at startup:

```
sudo systemctl disable apport.service
```

To check the status of the service:

```
systemctl status apport.service
```

Finally, you can also prevent the startup of a systemd service by masking it. The service will not be able to start (even manually) unless unmasked.

```
systemctl mask apport.service
```

This should create symlink from /etc/systemd/system/apport.service to /dev/null.
[fedoraproject.org](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd#How_do_I_start.2Fstop_or_enable.2Fdisable_services.3F)

Comment: It doesn't say which ubuntu rebase if I'm not mistaken. systemctl was introduced long after apport.

Comment: @der_michael Yes, this is a newer answer for newer versions of ubuntu which use systemd.

Answer (score 3):

Don't disable apport.  One of these days, you might have a sequence of crashes and never know it except for system bad behavior or some application-specific symptom.

The `/var/crash` directory is there to record any mishap.  You might need it some day.

Suggested procedure:

- Create a new folder E.g. `$HOME/crash` and copy all of the existing crash reports to it.
- `sudo rm /var/crash/*`
- `sudo reboot`

The repetitive crash pop-up behavior should now be gone. Also, the crash reports that you saved might be valuable in reporting a bug to launchpad.

Answer (score 3):

Since there's a bug in apport that breaks standard unix command line debugging, and this bug has been known since 2007 (I'm going to buy it a cake when it turns 10) (see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apport/+bug/160999) turning it off is far and away the best thing to do if you are trying to fix your own code.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just remove it entirely?

Version 16.04 LTS

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get remove apport
sudo rm /etc/cron.daily/apport
```

Also, might want to check this out:

[Removing popularity-contest without trashing the system?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84831/removing-popularity-contest-without-trashing-the-system/1027523#1027523)

New to 18.04:

[How to Opt Out of System Information Reports](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1027532/how-to-opt-out-of-system-information-reports)

Answer (score 0):

I found that I still wanted to disable Apport's crash handling in Python3. I had both tried disabling apport via cmdline (`sudo systemctl disable apport.service`), GUI (see [this hopefully-original blog post](https://vitux.com/how-to-disable-enable-automatic-error-reporting-in-ubuntu-18-04-lts/)), and via removal (`sudo apt purge`); however, Python backtraces showed `apport` still being present.

It seems like `python3-apport` is a prereq of `ubuntu-desktop` (relates [launchpad bug 1773087](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1773087)), so may be hard to remove it.

I then looked at the [Apport#Crash_interception](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Apport#Crash_interception), and seems like we can hack `/etc/python*/sitecustomize.py`.

As an example, the following worked (disabled `apport`) on my system for `python3.6`:

```sh
# N.B. Authenticate sudo first!
cat | sudo tee /etc/python3.6/sitecustomize.py <<EOF
## install the apport exception handler if available
#try:
#    import apport_python_hook
#except ImportError:
#    pass
#else:
#    apport_python_hook.install()
EOF
```

EDIT: Didn't try doing stuff like [isolated mode in `python3`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/using/cmdline.html#id2) - dunno if that'd work with Ubuntu-baked site customizations.

Comment: Filed a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/apport/+bug/1910304 `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`