# Constant Apport messages appearing

Tags: 12.04, gpu, apport

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I enable or disable Apport?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/93457/how-do-i-enable-or-disable-apport)

I have done a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04 onto my brand new Dell Inspiron 17R.  All went fine and everything works.

However, after updates and installing some programs from the software center I am almost constantly getting crash reports popping up in front of me from apport saying that there is some crash related to the GPU.  I do not notice anything wrong otherwise beside the message popping up.

When I follow the steps to report the error comes a window saying that I should not use that tool as it is not a development version but a stable version, so I am writing here.  Please point me to a forum where to report it and so on.

Comment: Same problem, but usually with `blueman-applet` on Dell Latitude E5500.