# "System program problem detected" message being shown often and without apparent reason

Tags: 12.04, notification

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I enable or disable Apport?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/93457/how-do-i-enable-or-disable-apport)

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 and for a couple of weeks I've had no problems at all with the distribution. Everything was perfect, but all of a sudden I started receiving the message "system program problem detected" in many occasions.

This message pops up right after login and when I am using Libreoffice and Skype. This problems happens very often and the applications crash after the message. The strangest thing is that the message also appears when the computer is apparently "doing nothing", with no applications being executed, which makes me think that the cause is some backgroud process.

Is this a general issue affecting many users? Is there anything I can do to solve this problem?

Comment: In that case if you choose yes to report problem then a dialogue should come up in which you can see the details about the crashing process by expanding the details tree-view. What was the output there?

Comment: I checked the details and it's written "Executable path: /usr/bin/Xorg". Is it a problem with my X server?

Comment: Yes, You can find the detailed report stored in `/var/crash` directory in the corresponding `.crash` file named after Xorg

Comment: Thank you Samik for the advice. However, I read the file and I couldn't understand what the problem was... it is full of memory adresses and references to kernel object files. In any case, I checked the Apport option to ignore future problems of this type.

Comment: Yes, that file contains information useful for the developers of that application who can trace the source of the problem from the memory map of the process and the linked shared libraries.