# How to disable "System problem detected" notification

Tags: 12.04, bug-reporting, bumblebee, apport

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I enable or disable Apport?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/93457/how-do-i-enable-or-disable-apport)

After installing the bumblebee drivers my system started reporting "System problem detected" around every hour. I already reported the error and am not very concerned about fixing it, because everything works fine.

How can I disable this notification?