# Start-up Application

Tags: boot, startup, startup-applications

I often get an error window after I booted my computer to the desktop. This is starting to annoy me. Is there a way to prevent, or disable or close it during boot up? Your help and time here is greatly appreciated. :)

(I'm a beginner with not an experience in programming. Or any relevance.)

Comment: Please tell us what the error window says.

Answer (score 0):

You can look in the Start programs. Just enter start into the Unity Shell, select Startup Programs and look in the list for possible apps.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of error window do you get? Is it something about Ubuntu experiencing an internal error? If this is the case, then the problem is that a debugging-tool named "Apport" is activated/present on your system. A solution to uninstall it has been posted to an earlier question here:

[How to disable "System problem detected" notification](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149096/how-to-disable-system-problem-detected-notification)

That solution involves using the commandline, but it also mentions using Ubuntu Software Centre to remove the app, which should be the easiest way, as it can be done with a few mouseclicks.