# System Error Report - Xorg

Tags: xorg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I enable or disable Apport?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/93457/how-do-i-enable-or-disable-apport)

[image]

[image]

I am getting this error every time I restart my Laptop (Lenovo Thinkpad W520). I did a little research before I posting here my question, but I couldn't find any answers. Can you please help with my problem? I also received a report of an error which is related with bluetoothd, but unfortunately I do not have a screenshot of the error.

Comment: The start-up music was removed from the 12.04 release, so no problem there.

Comment: I recommend editing those images into your question with the `img` tool in the editing toolbar.

Comment: I can't do that because I haven't got 10 in reputation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My advice would be to turn off Apport.

Apport is used in alpha and beta releases to help find and report bugs and would normally be switched off in a final release, but for some reason I have noticed it is on in 12.04.

This is causing unnecessary crash reports to pop up and it will be completely safe to turn off

To turn off Apport see this [How do I enable or disable Apport?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/93457/how-do-i-enable-or-disable-apport)

Comment: Okay,I disabled apport and I did a restart and there was no crash report.I think the problem is probably solved.Thanks all of you for your help.