# Ubuntu 12.04 issues internal error / system problem

Tags: apport

I am having massive problems with Ubuntu 12.04. After starting Ubuntu it takes maximum 20 seconds until the first error message shows up. I don't have the possibility to report the problem as immediately a new error message would show up and so on.

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 new however the problems are still there. When I was using Ubuntu 11.10 I did never have any error messages. Can I somehow post a error report (and how do I find it) here so one can figure out what the reason for the errors is.

Answer (score 6):

This is a bug with Ubuntu's error-reporting utility called Apport that a lot of people are experiencing. There is not currently a fix, but you can disable Apport so that it will not keep popping up.

To do this run

```
gksudo gedit /etc/apport.conf
```

After you enter in your password, Gedit will open up. 
You need to change the

enabled=1`line to`enabled=0`

Then, save the file and close Gedit. Apport will now not start when Ubuntu starts up. To stop it now without waiting for reboot, run

```
sudo service apport stop
```

Don't worry, this doesn't remove Apport. You can still use it to file a bug by running

`ubuntu-bug <applicationname>` - where `<applicationname>` is the name of the application you want to file a bug for.

- [How do I enable or disable Apport?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/93457/how-do-i-enable-or-disable-apport)