# "System Program Problem Detected"

Tags: system

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I enable or disable Apport?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/93457/how-do-i-enable-or-disable-apport)

I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and it started showing "System Program Problem detected".

I think it could be because my Windows is corrupt and I installed Ubuntu through WUBI.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to know what it means or how to get rid of messages like it?