# Frequent Crashes on fresh Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

Since the very beginning after I installed Ubuntu 12.04, it has been experiencing random crashes.

Sometimes it's the disk-utility, sometimes the qbittorrent, sometimes x11, other times it's apport, and many a times it's compiz.

Probing further on the crash, sometimes I get a message that some of my packages are out of date, which I update but some of them are already to the latest version.

Any fixes for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling apport, as it reports even the most unimportant of crashes

See: [How do I enable or disable Apport?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/93457/how-do-i-enable-or-disable-apport)

Comment: Thanks. So is this a case of apport going bad?