# Ubuntu crashes constantly and is upset with my video card. What can I do?

Tags: 12.04, intel-graphics

I knew I shouldn't have gone for the updates.
But I did. 
And now my lovely Ubuntu keeps on fighting with my graphics card - or so it seems from my point of view.

If I - read a up-to-480p video - or - dare visiting a Flash website - I get a (very short) freeze, with this crash report coming up again and again.

Report says:

```
Executable Path
/usr/share/apport/apport-gpu-error-intel.py
Package
xserver-xorg-video-intel (not installed)
Problem Type
Crash
etc etc

DistroRelease    
Ubuntu 12.04
```

I have it all but don't know what I should check in order to solve this.

If anyone knows what it's about, please let me know!

Thanks in advance,
denise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the error:

> `xserver-xorg-video-intel` (not installed)

it looks like your video driver is not installed.

Open a terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

After a reboot it should work as before.

Comment: Dear thom & BuZZ-dEE ~ Thank you very much for this. Answer from the terminal actually confirms that the package cant be installed: 'The following packages have unmet dependencies:

xserver-xorg-video-intel : Depends: xorg-video-abi-11
Depends: x-server-xorg-core (>= 2:1.10.99.901)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages'. I guess I know what's missing now. Might be linked to the special-12.04-DailyBuild-version I installed because of a threat on installing ubuntu on the latest Samsung hardware. For my issue, ill refer to the Launchpad team that studied the bug. Thx again!

Answer (score 1):

Do not try to install the `xserver-xorg-video-intel` package because your system could be damaged.

Ubuntu 12.04.**2** has not this package installed by default , instead it has

`xserver-xorg-video-intel-lts-quantal`

The kernel as Xserver as well , have been backported from Quantal(12.10) into Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS.

See the results of below commands

```
apt-cache policy xserver-xorg-video-intel-lts-quantal
apt-cache policy linux-image-generic-lts-quantal
```

As for the crash , it seems (to me) as an apport crash itself. Sometimes this can be happen. [See here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/93457/how-do-i-enable-or-disable-apport) on how you can disable apport and then keep track on your system to see if you actually have a real problem or not.

A system full update is always useful , so apply the commands below in a terminal

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```