# I regret choosing to hide a particular error, how can I show it again?

Tags: apport

When an application error occurs, Ubuntu prompts asking if you want to submit it and/or hide future errors *of this type* (e.g. a particular error from a particular application). I have opted to hide certain errors (but not others), but now I've changed my mind. Where can I find a list of the individual errors I've hidden, and opt to show some of them?

As a second-place alternative, can I choose to just show all errors again?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/93457/how-do-i-enable-or-disable-apport ;)

Comment: @Rinzwind so am I misguided in thinking that apport was hiding only particular types of errors, and I was actually switching the whole thing off and on?

Comment: This is the line in the config file (/etc/apport/crashdb.conf) "problem_types': ['Bug', 'Package']," so I guess you can ignore 2 types ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Various logs of errors can be found here:

```
/var/log
```

They can be read by opening a Terminal and typing:

```
cd /var/log
less *name_of_logfile*
```

The rest of the answer can be found here: [How do I enable or disable Apport?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/93457/how-do-i-enable-or-disable-apport)

Edit: also you can try to modify particular type of errors by editing `/etc/apport/crashdb.conf`:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/apport/crashdb.conf
```

Comment: Apport uses /var/crash/ and the files in there are the name of the crashed executable and the user id ;)

Comment: darn, I switched apport off and on again, so I've cleared whatever filters I had, I'll wait for them to build up again, but accept this in the meanwhile