# "Sorry, Ubuntu 13.04 has experienced an internal error" with upgrader core

Tags: upgrade

After I did all software updates in 13.04, I tried to upgrade to 13.10. I got the "Sorry, Ubuntu 13.04 has experienced an internal error" message.

It says the Package is "ubuntu-release-upgrader-core 1:0.192.13" and the Problem Type is "Crash".

What do I do now?

Answer (score 1):

I got same error at update.
Following an hour the #ubuntu irc channel gives me the pointers to related bug reports:

- Real-time signal 0: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/1241684
- Segmentation fault: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/1203534

how to got these message too?

open terminal and launch the Update Manager by typing `update-manager`

a first time i catch (The Dutch texts tells the actions it was performing):

> user@Hostname:~$ update-manager 
>   ...some messages about some password verifying stuff...
>   Er wordt gecontroleerd of er een nieuwe Ubuntu-uitgave is
>   'saucy.tar.gz' tegen  'saucy.tar.gz.gpg' verifiëren 
>   ‘saucy.tar.gz’ wordt uitgepakt
>   Segmentation fault (core dumped)

A next try delivers:

> user@Hostname:~$ update-manager 
>   Er wordt gecontroleerd of er een nieuwe Ubuntu-uitgave is
>   Real-time signal 0

This last message is which is reported at the bug mentioned above too.

It seems related to the Nvidia driver too, a temporary solution is switching to the nouveau driver to do the update. But in #ubuntu it was suggested that it seems reasonable to expect a fix for this. So just wait..

Answer (score 1):

"Sorry, Ubuntu 13.10 has experienced internal error" 
You can disable the apport by editing the following file:

`gksu gedit /etc/default/apport`

Now, in this file look for the line `# sudo service apport start force_start=1 enabled=1`

Change the `enabled=1` to `enabled=0`.

For more detail steps see here:

- [How do I enable or disable Apport?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/93457/how-do-i-enable-or-disable-apport)