# 64bit Ubuntu version issue

Tags: 14.04, 64-bit

I had installed Ubuntu 14.04 x64 recently on my Toshiba with Inter Core i3 and 2Gb of RAM. My CPU supports 64bit OS.

The 64bit installer finished faster compared to when I installed the 32bit version of 14.04. I'm not sure but I think the graphics are far more crisp than the graphics of 32bit. However, the system seems to run very slow on a 64bit. I know that when you run a 64bit OS, you should have more than 2Gb of RAM which this PC doesn't have. HOWEVER, when I looked at the system monitor, it doesn't even consume more than 60% of my RAM but it still runs slow. Why is that?

And how can I get the best out of my 64bit CPU architecture on a 2gb of RAM if that will always be the case?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, go into terminal:

Type:

```
top
```

It will show a list of processes.

then type:

```
c
```

c is to sort by CPU.

If you see Apport at the top with 98% CPU it's glichted.

Here is how to disable it:
[How do I enable or disable Apport?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/93457/how-do-i-enable-or-disable-apport)

Comment: And that solves it? I'll try to reinstall 64bit again later. Thanks for the input @mark

Comment: Yes once I disabled Apport it ran like a charm :)