# Everytime I start my computer I get the error "System has faced an internal error"

Tags: 14.04

Everytime I start my computer I  am getting  the error

> System has faced an internal error.

This is getting too frustarting. What do I do?

Comment: Is your system up to date? This question has been asked many times and most times it's solved by `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

You could try clearing the crash log directory:  `sudo rm -r /var/crash/*`  Occasionally something gets stuck in there.  I would encourage you, however, to examine the contents first, and see if there is something wrong in your system.

Comment: Which contents should I examine?

Comment: All that are in the directory, unless you believe them to be transient errors which have been corrected.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/93457/how-do-i-enable-or-disable-apport) answer may help, it explains that these errors are left over from bug fixing, and almost always harmless.

Comment: The errors are coming randomly anytime now. It started after I installed preload and cpufreq.

Comment: Yeah, disabling apport may help.

Comment: But if it faces some serious error?

Comment: What do you mean? It probably isn't serious.

Comment: But anytime after this if some error is serious?

Comment: Well what options does it give you? If you have a serious error, disabling the alert won't make much difference - I personally never click details.

Comment: It gives 2 options send report or don't send

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15288/discussion-between-tim-and-ritik).