# Ubuntu 16.04. Best way to disable apport?

Tags: 16.04, apport, logs

I have been searching for ways to do this in 16.04, but most instructions that I've found are for 14.04. I don't think it will work, since Ubuntu 16.04 uses `systemd`. Can someone please guide me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `systemctl` to accomplish your needs.

```
sudo systemctl status apport.service 

sudo systemctl stop apport.service 

sudo systemctl disable apport.service.
```

When learning to use `systemctl` you can often use tab completion, if you aren't aware of the full service names.

Comment: I didn't notice the possible duplicate comment when posting this, but http://askubuntu.com/a/637769/26160 does really have what dbz2k was looking for.

Comment: ok thanks I don't why didn't see that  when I was searching sorry