# "System program problem detected" message (Xorg) keeps popping up in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, xorg, system

I was wondering why I keep receiving this error messages every time Ubuntu starts:

[image]

I get two of them. I have reported one of them and clicked on details and was given this window:

[image]

The OS doesnt seem to be affected. It is Xorg related, but I don't really know how to fix it. The system itself seems to be stable and it always updates without any issues.

**UPDATE:** I have found [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/93457/how-do-i-enable-or-disable-apport) that helped me disable apport, but this still doesnt explain why I get an error messages and what is really happening to my OS. The system monitor doesnt show anything irregular (the OS is running well at the moment. I guess I'll need to check when it slows down again).

Comment: If misery loves company, this may cheer you up.  I see this same error every time I start Ubuntu 16.10 (kernel 4.8.0-27, nvidia-367-57, xorg 1:7.7+13ubuntu4). If you look in the folder /var/crash, you will see a file that fully describes the situation.  I don't know how to read that file :), but you could learn to and give me a lesson.

Comment: I just disabled the error message. Life is happy now.

Check the update to my post. It has a link explains how to disable apport. That should deals with it. :)