# apt or apt-get command throws "Bus error"

Tags: apt, updates

As of a few weeks ago, I cannot update/upgrade this jammy install:

```
$ lsb_release -a                                                                                                                                                                   
No LSB modules are available.                                                                                                                                                                
Distributor ID: Ubuntu                                                                                                                                                                       
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS                                                                                                                                                           
Release:        22.04                                                                                                                                                                        
Codename:       jammy
```

*Everything* else works normally...

I've tried many things, including but not limited to:

- nuking `/var/cache/apt/*`
- most of the suggestions for the other abandoned questions on
  askubuntu with this error

I'm happy to provide any other information and logs if it can help anybody help me.

keywords: bus core dump sudo apt update && apt list --upgradable

Comment: please add `ls -al /var/crash`  and try to disable apport/whooppsie https://askubuntu.com/questions/93457/how-do-i-enable-or-disable-apport

Comment: Thanks for your interest. I disabled apport and rebooted. dmesg no longer has any of those entries. apt is still broken. I'm afraid there is nothing in /var/crash.

Comment: Please can you add `sudo apt update && apt list --upgradable`  to your question?  I hope it is not an hardware issue.